# Getting how many checkboxes and radio buttons are checked

Tags: jquery, html, radio-button

So my question is how will I be able to count the checkboxes that are checked and the radio buttons that have a "yes" for an answer... the code I am using right now for the radio button is:

```
<label class="radio-inline">
<input form="ES3S" type="radio" name="Textbook'.$i.'" value="'.$Result[$i]['ID'].'"> Yes
</label>
<label class="radio-inline">
<input form="ES3S" type="radio" name="Textbook'.$i.'" value="-1">No
</label>


<span class="d-inline-block" data-toggle="popover" title="Error" data-content="This book is required by the school. If you want to cancel this out, proceed to the principals office with the book for review." data-trigger="hover">
<input form="ES3S" required checked onclick="return false;" type="checkbox" value="'.$Result[$i]['ID'].'" name="Textbook'.$i.'">
</span>
```

I was thinking of having a timer that does a checks every second to check how many check boxes and radio buttons are checked but I suppose that is very impractical.

```
SetInterval(ScriptUpdate, 1000);


function ScriptUpdate(param){


var check = $('#form').find('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length;
   alert('You have checked forms');
   return false;
}):    }
```

Cheers! Thanks in advance

Comment: What have you tried till now ?

Comment: Well I honestly don't know how how to do the radio buttons, but with the check boxes... ^ i edited them in :)

Comment: As you already know how to get checkbox count, maybe update your question specifically for radio buttons?

Comment: You don't want to do it by timer. When do you want to count it? Maybe you can do it with (custom) events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter based on "yes" text and checked radio button:

```
var radioButtonSelectedCount = $('input[type=radio]:checked').parent().filter(function() {
       return $(this).text().trim()=="Yes"
    }).length;
```

Comment: Worked great. Thanks! I was wondering if there is a way to make it applicable to certain radio types tho? thanks

Comment: Yes, It's possible with multiple radio types but for that we need to add a common attribute in all radio inputs. For example: <input form="ES3S" type="radio" name="Textbook.$2." value="-1" filter="radio">No</input> and appy following condition:     var radioButtonSelectedCount = $(document.querySelectorAll('input[filter=radio]:checked')).parent().filter(function() {
      return $(this).text().trim()=="Yes"
    }).length;

Comment: i do have common attributes in my forms.. I'm sorry. What i was trying to say is how should you do it in javascript

Comment: Code for javascript: var result=document.querySelectorAll('input[type=radio]:checked');
 var radioButtonSelectedCount = Array.prototype.filter.call( result, function( node ) {
        return node.parentNode.textContent.trim()=="Yes";
    }).length;

Answer (score 0):

Multiple ways to count the number of checkboxes/radio buttons checked, this is probably the simplest:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  alert($("input[type=radio]:checked").length);
});
```

Comment: I dont think it considers the response is yes/no :?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following:-

```
function checkboxes(){
    var checkBoxCheckedCount = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length;
    var radioButtonSelectedCount = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=radio]:checked').length;
    alert(checkBoxCheckedCount+radioButtonSelectedCount);

}
```

Then you can use the checkBoxCheckedCount and radioButtonSelectedCount Variables as per your needs.

Comment: This does not filter the 'yes' radio's.

Answer (score 0):

For radio buttons you can do something like this.

```
var countRadio = 0;
$('label.radio-inline').each(function(){
    if($(this).text() == "yes") {
        if($(this).children('input[type=radio]:checked').length > 0) {
            countRadio++;
        }
    }
});
console.log('Counted ' + countRadio  + ' Radiobuttons with yes');
```